# Why doesn't a HTTP reply from server specify the GET request to which the reply corresponds?

Tags: http

hen a server replies to a HTTP GET request why doesn't it specify in say some new header, the GET request for which this response was generated?

```
GET /counter.gif HTTP/1.1
Host: www.subbu.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0
Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 19 Dec 2011 00:12:28 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Dec 2011 15:29:54 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 24523
Content-Type: image/png
**Get-request: /counter.gif**
```

This will help in case the requests are pipelined. The server can send the replies in the order they are generated and the browser can interpret what the reply is for. I know HTTP is stateless but this seems like a simple optimization. Why do you think it might be a problem to implement this?

Comment: Potential security issue maybe?  If a server in the pipeline modifies the original request in any way, then the original client could end up getting back some info it's not privy to.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-pipeline-00#section-5

?

Answer (score 0):

If your using apache you may be referring to this functionnality: [Trace](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#traceenable)
When trace is set to extended, it reflect the request body.
Regards